# Why Index Usage Depend On Column Type

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, indexing

Here is my query:

```
SELECT u0_.value AS value0, u1_.property_uri AS property_uri1, count(u0_.id) AS sclr2, u2_.service_id AS sclr3 
FROM usc_connection_triple u0_ 
INNER JOIN usc_pro1_ ON u0_.property_id = u1_.id AND (u1_.status = 1) 
INNER JOIN usc_account_connection u3_ ON u0_.account_connection_id = u3_.id AND (u3_.status = 1) 
INNER JOIN usc_service_subscriber u2_ ON ((u2_.id = u3_.account_1_id OR u2_.id = u3_.account_2_id)) AND (u2_.status = 1) 
WHERE (u1_.create_analytics = '1') AND (u0_.status = 1) GROUP BY u2_.service_id, u0_.property_id, u0_.value;
```

I have created an index on u0_(usc_connection_triple) with following definition:

```
CREATE INDEX `temp` ON usc_connection_triple(property_id, account_connection_id, status, value);
```

This composite index is working great, 'explain' commands also show hints that mysql optimizer is gong to use it, like follow:

[image]

But, only when the 'value' column(type 'varchar') length is <= 255 . **Whenever I modify this column to a higher length**, the index's 'value' length only stays 255 max(which suppose to be and I am not worried about it) and **mysql optimizer discards the index totally**(instead, its using property_id foreign key index). The explain command now shows:

[image: Explain Command Result]

So, My questions are:

- why mysql optimizer discarding this?
- Is there any other better way to get this index working by modifying the index, other than 'USE INDEX'/'FORCE INDEX' command?
- Can I use a three column index discarding the fourth 'value' column? I tried, but seems still not being used.

Comment: Max index length is 255

Answer (score 1):

Look at the first execution plan and try to understand *how* it is using the index.

Especially the extra column gives use very valuable information:

**Using Where**

This means that it needs to apply some of the `where` clauses as filter predicate. I.e., it does not really use this index for all `where` clauses, just some of them.

**key_len = 4**

In the `key_len` column, MySQL tells us how much of the index it is really using efficiently. 4 means 4 bytes, which usually translates into a single `int` (or similar) column. That means, MySQL can only use the first column in the index efficiently (`property_id`). See below for a recommendation to fix it.

**Using Index**

Back to the *Extra* column. It should actually read 'Using Index Only.' That means that the index happens to have all the data (columns) that is required for this query. In other words, the query doesn't refer to any columns which are not part of the index. Consequently, there is no need for MySQL to make an additional IO operation to fetch more columns from the actual table. This feature is also called index-only scan. It can improve query performance hundred fold.

Now comes the limitation mentioned by @juergend: The maximum length of a index entry is limited. For InnoDB it is 767 bytes per column and  3072 bytes in total. However, these are *bytes* if you are using a multi-byte character set (UTF-8), the figure is smaller—as you observed.

So, when you attempt to index something that doesn't fit into the index, MySQL will silently truncate the index entry to fit in. However, that means it doesn't store the full column in the index anymore so it needs to do an extra hop to the table to fetch the full column. That can easily slow down your query by an factor of 100 :(

In the end, it might be better not using this index at all, or maybe another index which happens to be smaller (as in your case).

**Recommendation**

Fix the `using where` part first. Look at your join predicate:

```
INNER JOIN usc_pro1_ ON u0_.property_id = u1_.id AND (u1_.status = 1)
```

and the index

```
ON usc_connection_triple(property_id, account_connection_id, status, value)
```

Efficient index use is only possible on the left-hand side columns. Imagine a prided telephone book—typically ordered by last name, first name. Now try to find all people with first name "Sarah" in this telephone book. A similar problem is happening here. The first column `property_id` is fine, it is mentioned in the query with an equality condition. However, the next index column `account_connection_id` is not mentioned in the where clause at all. That's the reason it can use the next column `status` only as filter.

So, the first idea might be to re-order the index like so:

```
ON usc_connection_triple(property_id, status, account_connection_id, value)
```

This would make the `using where` disappear (although, depending on the MySQL version it sometimes doesn't).

You might even consider to put `status` first because it seems to be an always-present where clause. That would even allow ordering on `property_id` using the index in some cases (not in yours, because it's not the first column in your `order by` clause).

If you cannot make the query doing an index-only scan (showing `using index` in extra), you should remove the columns that are not used in the `where` clause from the index.

**References**

- [Filter predicates in the where-clause ("Using Where")](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/the-equals-operator/concatenated-keys)
- [Index-only Scan](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-only-scan-covering-index)
- [Reading MySQL execution plans](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/explain-plan/mysql/operations)

Comment: Thanks for detailed info! I finally got a way to get the index used by mysql optimizer(by changing order as you suggested). But interesting thing is, still the performance is same as before index, no improvement at all! Any suggestion on this?